# Another phrasing for the convergence of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers and $L$ be a real number. For every neighborhood $U$ of $L$ there are infinitely many terms of $(a_n)$ in $U$, necessarily means that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$? If we look at the definition for limit of a sequence, it seems that they are equivalent. There is a possibility that convergence is a stronger condition than former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made a logical error, which is very common among the inexperienced. The definition says

> If $(a_n)_n$ is a sequence, we say $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$ if for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is an $N$ so that $ \lvert a_n - L \rvert < \varepsilon $ for every $n>N$.

To put this into natural language, this says that whatever $\varepsilon$ is, we can always find an $N$ so that after $N$, there are no terms of the sequence outside the set $(L-\varepsilon,L+\varepsilon)$.

Now to phrase this more in your language, given any neighbourhood $U$ (i.e. a set of the form $(L-\varepsilon,L+\varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon$), there is always a point after which all terms of the sequence are in this neighbourhood.

Or, given any neigbourhood $U$ of $L$, the sequence $(a_n)$ eventually lies in $U$.

So far, everything is fine. The problem comes now: "eventually P(n) always holds" (i.e. "P(n) for every n after a certain point") is not the same as "there are infinitely many n so that P(n)". For example, there are infinitely many even integers, but it is not true that eventually, every integer is even. Instead, you want what superficially looks like the opposite: "there are not infinitely many n so that P(n) does not hold". (Does this work? Yes: if there are only finitely many n, there is a largest one for which P is not true, and after this P(X) is true for every X. On the other hand, if P(n) is true after a certain point N, then the set where it is not true is a subset of the first N n's, which is finite.)

So the statement should be:

> If $(a_n)_n$ is a sequence, $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$ if for every neighbourhood $U$ of $L$, there are only finitely many $n$ so that $a_n$ is not in $U$.

---

And for future reference, the equivalences are

- "P(n) holds eventually" $\iff$ "There are only finitely many n for which P(n) does not hold"/"There are not infinitely many n for which P(n) does not hold"
- "P(n) holds for infinitely many n" $\iff$ "There is no largest n for which P(n) holds"

Comment: Thanks a lot, so if for every neighborhood $U$ of $L$ there are infinitely many terms of $(a_n)$ in $U$ means that there is a subsequence which converges to $L$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's basically what a subsequence is: an infinite subset of a sequence (retaining the ordering). The key here is you can find a nested set of neigbourhoods ($U_n \supset U_m$ for $m>n$) that shrink to $L$.This allows you to construct a subsequence inductively: because there are infinitely many $a_k$ in each $U_n$ you can pick one you haven't used yet to be $a_{k(n)} \in U_n$, and then since the sequence of neighbourhoods is nested, all the subsequent $a_{k(m)}$ also lie in $U_n$. [...]

Comment: [...] It follows that eventually $(a_{k(i)})_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ lies in $U_n$ for each $n$, and every neighbourhood contains a $U_n$ for some $n$, so for any neighourhood $V$, $a_{k(i)}$ is eventually in $U_n$, and so eventually in $V$.

Comment: I think in the last paragraph, it should be "There are not infinitely many n for which P(n) does not hold".

Comment: "P(n) holds eventually" $\implies$ "P(n) holds for infinitely many n". Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, both of those are correct.

Comment: It was really helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Let the sequence be $1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, \ldots$ and let $L = 1$. Then every neighborhood of $L$ contains infinitely many terms of the sequence, but the sequence does not converge to $L$.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why these statements differ? I mean how we can add some conditions to the first statement to get definition of convergence?

Comment: And so we can conclude that there is a subsequence of $(a_n)$ which converges to $L$, right?

Comment: I think you want something like that for every neighborhood U of L there are almost all (a_n) in that neighborhood (where almost all means all but finitely many).

Comment: @hal4math Can you elaborate please?

Comment: It is really just the definition of convergence of a sequence, where instead of for all $\varepsilon >0$ you want for all neighborhoods that there exists a $N\in\mathbb{N}$  such that for all $n > N$ holds $|L-a_n| < \varepsilon$ respectively only finitly many elements lie outside the choosen neighborhood.

Comment: I do think that you are right and one can conclude that there is a subsequence which will converge. I think you can just leave out all the other (possibly infinite many) elements to get that subsequence.